# Are there any MF standard fast primes for Mirrorless APS-C systems that are not available for APS-C DSLRs?

Tags: prime, mirrorless, fast-lenses

I am currently using the Canon 700D and think of shifting to a Fujifilm X-T1. I came across the kamlan f/1.1 which is a very fast standard/short telephoto lens. I am looking for sub-750 USD lens, that provides standard/short telephoto focal lengths and fast apertures that cannot work on my Canon APS-C camera.

Other lens I found near this price range but not exactly in it:

Mikaton 50 f/0.95

Examples with good image quality fully open/less than F/2 are a bonus. Corner sharpness must be good too as my compositions tend to have some detail near the corners as well.

Comment: EF-M is for mirrorless only, the 22mm f/2 has good quality and if you switch it to M instead of AF; it is an MF, (almost) standard prime (as in: cropped).

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any lenses that are made for the mirrorless system only and not DSLRs?

Yes, there are many such lenses.

The Sony E mount system, the Fuji X system, The Canon EF-M system, etc.

> I was wondering whether there are cheap MF standard primes.

That all depends on how you define "cheap." Some people consider a $200 lens to be expensive, others think a $700 lens is cheap.

> Some examples with good image quality will be appreciated.

The [Kamlan 50mm f/1.1](https://www.ephotozine.com/article/sainsonic-kamlan-50mm-f-1-1-lens-review-31408) is available in the Sony E-mount system, which is a mirrorless only lens mount.